# How to add the passed value into NSMutableArray on second viewController ios

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

In objective-c, I have created two `UIViewControllers` FirstViewController and SecondViewController. In Storyboard I have created a segue from FirstViewController to the SecondViewController, then ctrl-drag buttonA on SecondViewController to Exit to create unwind segue back from SecondViewController to the FirstViewController.

Everytime from FirstViewController to the SecondViewController I pass a NSString, and on the SecondViewController, I have a `NSMutableArray`, and every time, once I have the `NSString` passed from FirstViewController, I add it into the `NSMutableArray`, however, after few times back and forth, the `NSMutableArray` on SecondViewController only contains one NSString. Seems that everytime when go back to the FirstViewController and back to SecondViewController, the `NSMutableArray` reset to nil.

On FirstViewControll.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CamToPhotoReviewSegue"]) {
        SecondViewController *prc = (SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        prc.photoName = photoNameToPhotoReviewController;
    }

}
```

One SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.arrayOfPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Push photo name into arrayOfPhotos
    [self.arrayOfPhotos addObject:photoName];
}
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: You may be initialising the array in second view controller. Create a static variable instead

Answer (score 0):

When you go back to the `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController` is popped off of the navigation stack and deallocated because it is no longer in use. When you come back to the `SecondViewController` again, a new instance of it is being pushed onto the navigation stack because it is a "new" view controller being viewed. Since the `NSMutableArray` with your string in it is an instance field of `SecondViewController`, it gets deallocated when the second view controller gets deallocated.

To prevent the `NSMutableArray` from being "reset" every time, use an external data object. The data object will have the array in it, and `FirstViewController` will create the data object (which creates the array in `init`). Then, when `prepareForSegue` is called, `FirstViewController` needs to add the string to the data object's array, then pass the data object to `SecondViewController` just like you are currently passing the string.

By doing this, when `secondViewController` gets deallocated, the data object (and therefore the array) is not erased as well because `firstViewController` is still using it.

```
//the data object's .h
@interface Data:NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray* array;
}
@end

//in FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //declare myData in the .h
    myData = [[Data alloc] init];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"FirstToSecondSegue"])
    {
        SecondViewController* svc = (SecondViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        myData.array.addObject(myCoolString);
        svc.myData = myData;
    }
}

//in SecondViewController.h
@interface SecondViewController:UIViewController
{
    Data* myData;
}
@end
```

Comment: looks like a better solution, I will try it. thanks!